# How to open a MS Excel template from MS Access form, then use a button from the Excel template to export it back to Access?

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I'm developing a database to manage mechanical parts/assemblies. I need the ability to have users add multiple components all at once.  To do this, I want the user to press a button on an Access form that pulls up an Excel template.  Once the user populates the template, they press a button in Excel to load that data back into Access.  From there, I think I know enough VBA to sort through the data and put it where it needs to be.

I am a MechE by trade, so I'm not exactly in my element here. Any help is appreciated. I am using MS Office 2013.

Comment: Sounds like an awfully complicated way to do things. Why not create an Access form for data entry? -- Also, we're not here to write your application. Try to do some research first, and when you have a **specific** problem, ask here.

Comment: Did you read the question? I do have an access form, but I need to allow the user to add whole tables from spreadsheets. I did research and even though there's a lot of info on how to import to access, there isn't a ton on exporting from excel like this. I'm not asking you to write my code, and I don't think this is a particularly vague question.  Next time actually read what I've already done, and consider saying something helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to start by making sure in MS Access that you have 'Microsoft 15.0 Object Library' active in your vba references before you start.  To do this from your 'vba' window go to Tools > References and then everything is in alpha order after the references you have selected already.

```
Dim xl as excel.application
Dim wbk as excel.workbook
Dim tpath as string

'This creates a new instance of excel.
Set xl = CreateObject("Excel.Application",)
tpath = "X:\NetworkPath\OrSharedLocation\TemplateName.xlsx" 
'replace what is inside the quotes with the actual full path name of the file
'I would not use a drive letter unless everyone in the org uses the same drive letter to map to.
Set wbk = xl.wbk.open tpath
```

That will open the 'Excel' file from 'MS Access'.
To do the other part I honestly would create a button that saved the excel file to the person's C:\TEMP location then uses the transferspreadsheet method in access vba to import it back into Access.  It would be shorter code and in my experience cause less errors in Access.

The excel button would handle the whole process but you would add a module to Access. Again you have to make sure you have the Access Object Reference checked in the reference library.
Excel VBA:

```
Dim ACC as Access.Application
Dim dbPath as String
SaveAs "C:\Temp\ATemplate.xlsx" 
dbpath = "yourDatabasePathGoesHere"
Set ACC = CreateObject("Access.Application")
With ACC
     .OpenCurrentDatabase dbpath
     .Run "GetTemplate"
    .Quit
Wend
Set ACC = Nothing
```

Then in Access create a procedure:

```
Sub GetTemplate()
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport,,"NameOfAccessTable","C:\TEMP\ATemplate.xlsx",True

End Sub
```

Sorry for the long post... I think that should get you where you need to be.